# Chinese chars in input XML cause an XSLT transformation to spew out invalid character references in output XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, unicode, xalan

I'm trying to figure out why my simple XSLT transformation, which is supposed to transform XML to XML, doesn't seem to be able to achieve that.

The transformation simply copies everything:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With an input XML file, such as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns="uri:foo">
  <name>丕</name>
</foo>
```

the following is the result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns="uri:foo">
  <name>丕&#55360;&#56326;&#55360;&#56325;&#55360;&#56333;&#55360;&#56384;</name>
</foo>
```

The tools I'm using all rely on (Java) Apache Xalan 2.7.1 XSLT processor, including Eclipse (Mars) with the XSL Developer Tools plugin, where I created this sample.

The latter plugin claims the input XML is well formed, but the output XML isn't (character reference &#55360 is an invalid XML character).

Why is my XSLT processor generating invalid XML and how do I prevent it from doing so?

The actual code is along the lines of this (you need [Xalan](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/downloads.html) in your classpath):

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class XSLTTest {

    private final TransformerFactory xalanTransFact;

    public XSLTTest() {
        xalanTransFact = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();
    }

    public Templates createCustomTransformation(
            File transformation
    ) throws TransformerException, IOException {
        InputStreamReader readerTransformation = null;
        try {
            readerTransformation = new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(transformation), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);  
            Templates transformer = xalanTransFact.newTemplates(
                    new StreamSource(readerTransformation)
            );
            return transformer;
        } catch (TransformerException | IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (readerTransformation != null) {
                    readerTransformation.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {} 
        }
    }

    public File applyCustomTransformation(
            Transformer transformer, Reader transformeeReader, Path out, 
            boolean indent
    ) throws TransformerException, IOException {
        Writer writer = null;
        try {

            File file = out.toFile();
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            if (indent) {
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(
                        "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount",
                        String.valueOf(2));
            }
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");

            transformer.transform(
                    new StreamSource(transformeeReader),
                    new StreamResult(writer));

            return file;

        } catch (TransformerException | IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {      
            try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }

    private void saveToFile(File selectedFile, String content)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(selectedFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            writer.write(content);
            writer.flush();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        String xslText = "" +
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
"<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"\n" +
"    version=\"1.0\">\n" +
"    <xsl:output method=\"xml\" encoding=\"utf-8\" />\n" +
"    <xsl:template match=\"*|@*\">\n" +
"        <xsl:copy>\n" +
"            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"*|@*|text()\" />\n" +
"        </xsl:copy>\n" +
"    </xsl:template>\n" +
"</xsl:stylesheet>";

        String xmlToParse = "" +
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
"<foo xmlns=\"uri:foo\">\n" +
"  <name>丕</name>\n" +
"</foo>";

        XSLTTest test = new XSLTTest();

        Path xsl = Files.createTempFile("test", ".xsl");
        test.saveToFile(xsl.toFile(), xslText);        
        Templates templates = test.createCustomTransformation(xsl.toFile());
        Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();

        Path xml = Files.createTempFile("test-out", ".xml");
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlToParse);
        test.applyCustomTransformation(transformer, reader, xml, true);

        System.out.println("Result is at: " + xml.toString());
    }
}
```

For reasons, I am not able to switch to another XSLT processor.

Comment: Those character references are UTF-16 surrogate pairs, since all of the characters except the first one are in the U+2nnnn Unicode block.  Edit your question and show us the code that does the transformation;  it may not be specifying the output encoding correctly.

Comment: Is there any Java code involved too? Consider showing that as well to see whether it is at least possible to avoid the problem by changing the code. And in the Java world it is rather easy to switch to another XSLT processor like Saxon to check whether it gives the desired output.

Comment: @VGR: The java code would be Eclipse Mars code base..

Comment: @Martin: The java code would be Eclipse Mars code base..

Comment: I’m not sure I understand.  What action do you personally take in order to trigger the XSLT processing, if you didn’t write code to do it?

Comment: @VGR: the transformation was performed inside Eclipse IDE using an XSL Run configuration, provided by XSL Developer Tools Eclipse plugin (basically an XSLT debugger). All files are UTF-8 encoded, I do not know how they implement actual transforms, but it is indeed Java.

Comment: It might be a problem with that plugin, then.  I just wrote a three-line program that uses the javax.xml.transform package and uses your input files, and the result was correct;  no surrogate pairs were present in the output.  Can the plugin be configured to use the Java SE XSL transform implementation (that is, javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory)?

Comment: @VGR, the thing is, the exact same thing happens inside my own (Java) code, so whatever they are doing wrong, I'm also doing in my code. I'll put together a self contained runnable example that demonstrates this, hopefully soon.

Comment: It might also be useful to mention which version of Java you’re using.  I ran my test with Java 8 and Java 11.

Comment: @VGR, my code uses Java 8, but the actual XSLT processor is not the default one. An external distribution of Xalan 2.7.1 is being used.

Comment: @VGR, I edited the question with an example. The code should reflect how the transformation is usually performed.

Comment: Looks like it’s a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2419

Comment: Oh, man.. I stepped on an ancient mine there. Thanks, @VGR.

Answer (score 0):

As @VGR wrote in a comment, this is a manifestation of bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2419.

A comment on their JIRA suggests a workaround - use UTF-16 as output encoding for the transformation, instead of UTF-8, since the bug only affects the latter.

So, in my example, line

```java
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
```

needs to be replaced with

```java
// workaround for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2419
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-16");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");            
writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n");
```

while everything else stays the same. The actual files are still written as UTF-8, but the transformation will be handled as UTF-16 internally.